# Trying to convert molecular dynamics output files into csv files with Python

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I perform molecular dynamics wherein I process the output such that I get excel-like files as in:

```
-rw-r--r--  1   staff  210030 Jan 20 16:25 summary.EKTOT
-rw-r--r--  1   staff  210030 Jan 20 16:25 summary.EPTOT
-rw-r--r--@ 1   staff  210030 Jan 20 16:25 summary.ETOT
-rw-r--r--  1   staff  154022 Jan 20 16:25 summary.PRES
-rw-r--r--@ 1   staff  105015 Jan 20 16:25 summary.DENSITY
-rw-r--r--@ 1   staff  105015 Jan 20 16:25 summary.EKCMT
-rw-r--r--  1   staff  105015 Jan 20 16:25 summary.TSOLUTE
-rw-r--r--  1   staff  105015 Jan 20 16:25 summary.TSOLVENT
-rw-r--r--  1   staff  105015 Jan 20 16:25 summary.VOLUME
```

I have downloaded these files to my computer with the goal of turning them all into csv/excel files such that the data can be entered and graphed into a jupyter notebook for record keeping. I have written the following code for this purpose (trying one file for the demo):

```
import pandas as pd

    import os    
    os.chdir("Users/Downloads/analysis_BK_1")
    with open(summary.DENSITY) as infile, open('summ_density.csv', 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line.replace(' ', ','))
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 /Users/chrisgaughan/Desktop/Amber_Research_2020/excel_converter.py
(base) Chriss-MacBook-Pro:feature-engineering-for-machine-learning chris$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3 /Users/chrisgaughan/Desktop/Amber_Research_2020/excel_converter.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Desktop/Amber_Research_2020/excel_converter.py", line 3, in <module>
    os.chdir("Users/Downloads/analysis_BK_1")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users/chrisgaughan/Downloads/analysis_BK_1'
```

I have indeed checked that I am in the correct directory..if that really has anything to do with it.

Can someone please lend a hand?

Comment: As far as I can tell, `with open('summary.DENSITY')` should be in quotes.

Comment: `Users/Downloads/analysis_BK_1` should it not be `/Users/chrisgaughan/Downloads/analysis_BK_1`. (note the leading slash...)

Comment: I would suggest don't change the directories , use the absolute paths instead and it should work.

Comment: Thanks to McKinney and Brennan, combined you had the right answers. I lift my pint of Guinness to you.